# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Node/MongoDB async await scenario

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, async-await

I'm just transitioning to `async`/`await` and have been learning from these resources:

https://javascript.info/async-await

https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/truly-understanding-async-await-491dd580500e

https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c

I think I have understood the main points:

1. adding `async` before a function definition will ensure any value returned is a `promise`
2. adding `await` before the call to the `async` function will "pause" the program until a result is returned
3. the function that *contains* `await` must also have the `async` keyword before its declaration (any 'parent' functions of the container do not require the `async` keyword)
4. the 'await-dependent' declarations should be wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block

So I am thinking an ideal `async`/`await` scenario would look like this:

```
async function thisWillTakeAges() {

    // query a database, fetch external content etc
    return desired_value;

}


async function iLoveProgramming() {

    try {
        var desired_value = await thisWillTakeAges();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    // do things with 'desired_value' once it has been returned

}
```

I am trying to incorporate this into an application with the following code:

```
function get_reset_password_secret(reset_password_user_id) {

    // ...

    collection.findOne(query, options, async function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {

            if (result !== null) {

                // ..

                return secret;

            }
        }
    });

}


// middleware
const api_resource_get = async (req, res) => {

    // ...

    try {
        var secret = await get_reset_password_secret(reset_password_user_id);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error here at api_resource_get(): " + err);
    }

    var forgotten_password_token = jwt.sign({ user_email: user_email }, secret);

    // ... 

}


// route handler
app.route("/api/:api_version/resource")
    .get(api_resource_get);
```

I am getting this error:

> (node:14484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error:
>   secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

So there are two issues:

- Why am I getting this error?
- Why is the program stating that the error is unhandled when I do have a `try`/`catch` block (which is not console logging the error)?

In regards to the first issue, perhaps it is because `get_reset_password_secret()` also needs the `async` keyword before it?

In regards to the second issue, I'm not sure why the `catch` block is not being recognised.

Comment: [`findOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOne) and all other related methods already return a Promise natively. You cannot mark a "callback" with `async` ( or at least not in the way you are expecting ), so instead of using callbacks use the native Promise instead. i.e `return collection.findOne(query,options)` which returns a Promise you can actually `await`.